# How do I store all command outputs and errors?

Tags: command-line, bash, python, capture

#### Hi there!

I need to capture all command, stdout and stderr without any addition to the commands.
I mean, that I have to save/store the output of these:

1. $ echo 'test'
2. $ ls -l
3. $ cat some_file

---

### commands.file

> 1. alex@bender:/pwd$ echo 'test'
> 2. alex@bender:/pwd$ ls
> 3. alex@bender:/pwd$ cat some_file
> 4. alex@bender:/pwd$ fsdfsdfsd

---

### stdout.file

> 1. test
> 2. test.txt some_file
> 3. some file content

---

### stderr.file

> _4. fsdfsdfsd

as for first part of question, I found script, which use a trap and before evaluating the command it stores the command to log.
But what about storing output?
repeat: this should be solved without any additions to command.
I mean, after running script, I dont need to write, for example first command
*ls **> log.file*** I want see it without "***>log.file***"

I write some python script, it works like command wrapper.

> if **name** == '**main**':
>       user = os.getlogin()
>       machine_name = os.uname()[1]

```
stdinbuff = open('commands', 'w')                                             
stdoutbuff = open('outs', 'w')                                                

command_string = 1                                                            
while command_string != '0':                                                  

    a = user + '@' + machine_name + ":" + os.getcwd() + '>';                  
    a = a.replace('/home/', '~/')                                             
    print a,                                                                  
    command_string = raw_input()                                              
    command_args = command_string.split()                                     

    proc = subprocess.Popen(command_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)             
    (out, err) = proc.communicate()                                           
    print out                                                                 

    stdinbuff.write(command_string+'\n')                                      
    stdoutbuff.write(out+'\n')                                                

stdinbuff.close()                                                                 
stdoutbuff.close()
```

but in this wrapper, I can't use autocomplete, like in bash, and this script can't store all what I want.

Maybe, someone could tell me, what I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with python pty module:
[using a pseudo-terminal to record all input and output of a terminal session](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pty.html#example).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the `screen` tool can do the trick for you with the screen logging function. Just simply start `screen` in commandline and with the keys `CTRL-a + H` (first Combination of `CTRL + a` and then a capital H with `SHIFT + H`, just to clarify) everything will be logged in the file `screenlog.0`. The directory where the logfile is found depends on where you started screen, i. e. if you started screen in your $HOME then the logfile will be found there.

Comment: Great solution! You may want to clarify, that `A` is just the key `a`, but `H` refers to a capital `H`. So the combination effectively becomes `CTRL-A` and then `SHIFT-H`.

Comment: Thanks **noggerl**, but, may be you know another way to do this, because at some time i need to patch output on the fly..

Comment: The only solution for this i've got in my mind is start a second `screen`. In that `screen` you can start a script which patches the output of the other `screen` at runtime (i. e. in python, maybe a shellscript could do). Maybe I can help you a little more when you tell me what you're trying to do.
@Tim: thanks for your hint, i've edited my solution with your suggestions.